# How to get process PID for manual lock mechanism in Python?

Tags: python, linux, locking

I would like to make a simple locking mechanism in Python without having to rely on the existing libraries for locking (namely `fcntl` and probably others)

I already have a small stub, but after searching for a bit I couldn't find a good on answer on how to manually create the lock file and put the process PID inside. Here is my stub:

```
dir_name = "/var/lock/mycompany"
file_name = "myapp.pid"
lock = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)

if os.path.exists(lock):
    print >> sys.stderr, "already running under %s, exiting..." % lock
    # display process PID contained in the file, not relevant to my question
    sys.exit(ERROR_LOCK)
else:
    # create the file 'lock' and put the process PID inside
```

How can I get the current process PID and put it inside the `lock` file? I thought about looking at `/proc` filesystem but that seems a bit too much for such a simple task.

Thanks.

Comment: `open(lock, 'w').write(os.getpid())`

Comment: Perfect answer thanks, guess I don't need to bother with /proc after all...

Comment: just for your info- if you ever need to interrogate a process in proc, you can do it with `/proc/self`.  `/proc/self` is always a symlink to the calling process.  However, for just gleaning the PID, it is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open(lock, 'w').write(os.getpid())`

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getpid

Answer (score 0):

Don't neglect to convert the result of os.getpid() to a string with str(os.getpid()).  write wants a string argument.