# Implementing a full Python Unix-style daemon process

Tags: python, unix, daemon

I'm currently trying to manually create a simple daemon process, I don't want to use the existing externals libraries to avoid overhead.

I'm currently checking when my process runs that it doesn't have a PID file already created (meaning it's running), like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10216402/1332690).

I also have a **daemonizing** module to detach the PID from current process and redirect stdout and stderr (so my daemon will keep running even if I end my session):

```
import os
import sys

def daemonize(stdin="/dev/null", stdout="/dev/null", stderr="/dev/null"):
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e: 
        sys.stderr.write ("fork #1 failed: (%d) %s\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror) )
        sys.exit(1)

    os.chdir("/") 
    os.umask(0) 
    os.setsid() 

    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e: 
        sys.stderr.write ("fork #2 failed: (%d) %s\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror) )
        sys.exit(1)

    stdin_par = os.path.dirname(stdin)
    stdout_par = os.path.dirname(stdout)
    stderr_par = os.path.dirname(stderr)
    if not stdin_par:
        os.path.makedirs(stdin_par)
    if not stdout_par:
        os.path.makedirs(stdout_par)
    if not stderr_par:
        os.path.makedirs(stderr_par)

    si = open(stdin, 'r')
    so = open(stdout, 'a+')
    se = open(stderr, 'a+', 0)
    os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
```

So currently I can run my process like sample line below and it will run my daemon correctly:

```
>$ python myapp.py
```

But to stop it, I have to grep the PID (or take it from the lock file) and manually erase the PID after:

```
>$ ps -ef | grep myapp
xxxxx  11901     1  0 19:48 ?        00:00:00 python src/myapp.py
xxxxx  12282  7600  0 19:54 pts/7    00:00:00 grep myapp
>$ kill -9 11901
>$ rm -rf /path/to/lock.pid
```

I'd like to have a more Unix-like daemon where I can manage the daemon lifecycle with the following commands:

```
>$ python myapp.py start
>$ python myapp.py stop
>$ python myapp.py restart
```

I can certainly do it with the `argparse` module, but that seems a bit tedious and ugly.

Do you know a simple and elegant solution to have a Unix-style daemon process in Python?

Comment: I think you are confusing daemon processes with startup scripts.  They are usually different things.  I mean, a _Unix-like_ daemon behaviour does not have to include stopping and restarting facilities, it is just the TTY detaching mechanism.

Comment: You can try using the `daemon` package: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/

Comment: @C2H5OH Yes you're right, i actually have the daemonization process working fine, but i'd like in the end to have it managed by the python application itself, without having to kill or rm manually.

Comment: @linker: Then you would have to implement whatever PID finding mechanism you like and then send that process a signal.  There is no mystery.

Comment: That's actually what I'm looking for, if you know how to do this feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking a bit more I found a great example that does just this [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

It uses a generic `Daemon` class, which can be subclassed afterwards:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, time, atexit
from signal import SIGTERM

class Daemon:
        """
        A generic daemon class.

        Usage: subclass the Daemon class and override the run() method
        """
        def __init__(self, pidfile, stdin='/dev/null', stdout='/dev/null', stderr='/dev/null'):
                self.stdin = stdin
                self.stdout = stdout
                self.stderr = stderr
                self.pidfile = pidfile

        def daemonize(self):
                """
                do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced
                Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
                http://www.erlenstar.demon.co.uk/unix/faq_2.html#SEC16
                """
                try:
                        pid = os.fork()
                        if pid > 0:
                                # exit first parent
                                sys.exit(0)
                except OSError, e:
                        sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
                        sys.exit(1)

                # decouple from parent environment
                os.chdir("/")
                os.setsid()
                os.umask(0)

                # do second fork
                try:
                        pid = os.fork()
                        if pid > 0:
                                # exit from second parent
                                sys.exit(0)
                except OSError, e:
                        sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
                        sys.exit(1)

                # redirect standard file descriptors
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.stderr.flush()
                si = file(self.stdin, 'r')
                so = file(self.stdout, 'a+')
                se = file(self.stderr, 'a+', 0)
                os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
                os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
                os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

                # write pidfile
                atexit.register(self.delpid)
                pid = str(os.getpid())
                file(self.pidfile,'w+').write("%s\n" % pid)

        def delpid(self):
                os.remove(self.pidfile)

        def start(self):
                """
                Start the daemon
                """
                # Check for a pidfile to see if the daemon already runs
                try:
                        pf = file(self.pidfile,'r')
                        pid = int(pf.read().strip())
                        pf.close()
                except IOError:
                        pid = None

                if pid:
                        message = "pidfile %s already exist. Daemon already running?\n"
                        sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
                        sys.exit(1)

                # Start the daemon
                self.daemonize()
                self.run()

        def stop(self):
                """
                Stop the daemon
                """
                # Get the pid from the pidfile
                try:
                        pf = file(self.pidfile,'r')
                        pid = int(pf.read().strip())
                        pf.close()
                except IOError:
                        pid = None

                if not pid:
                        message = "pidfile %s does not exist. Daemon not running?\n"
                        sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
                        return # not an error in a restart

                # Try killing the daemon process       
                try:
                        while 1:
                                os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)
                                time.sleep(0.1)
                except OSError, err:
                        err = str(err)
                        if err.find("No such process") > 0:
                                if os.path.exists(self.pidfile):
                                        os.remove(self.pidfile)
                        else:
                                print str(err)
                                sys.exit(1)

        def restart(self):
                """
                Restart the daemon
                """
                self.stop()
                self.start()

        def run(self):
                """
                You should override this method when you subclass Daemon. It will be called after the process has been
            daemonized by start() or restart().
                """
```

Once you have this module, you can do the following to have all different modes of your daemon:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, time
from daemon import Daemon

class MyDaemon(Daemon):
        def run(self):
                while True:
                        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
                if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
                        daemon.start()
                elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
                        daemon.stop()
                elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
                        daemon.restart()
                else:
                        print "Unknown command"
                        sys.exit(2)
                sys.exit(0)
        else:
                print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
                sys.exit(2)
```

Hope that helps other people who get stuck on the same problem !

Comment: Note that the second fork is not necessary in modern Unices.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ease the process of signaling the daemon process, we use the following function at work:

```
def set_procname(name):
    import ctypes
    lc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
    lc.prctl(15, name[:15])
```

Then, the daemon process can use it:

```
set_procname("foo")
```

And then we can do `pkill foo` to send a `TERM` signal.  This is **not** a proper answer but it could be useful.  However, the `set_procname()` function has some limitations:

- It only works on Linux kernels.
- You can only use up to 15 characters for the process name.
- If you launch more instances of the same daemon process, `pkill` will signal them all.