# python app configured to run as system.d service on raspberry pi. Service can be started manually but does not start during boot

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, systemd

I have written a python flask app that starts a local webserver on a raspberri pi.
Then I have configured the app to be started as a service during boot time via a system.d script located in /etc/init.d

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2359 Dez 17 18:17 VolumioEmilClient`

I enabled the Service via `sudo update-rc.d VolumioEmilClient defaults`
Afterwards I reboot the pi but the service won't start automatically.

When trying to start the service manually on the console with:
`sudo systemctl start VolumioEmilClient`
or alternatively via
`/etc/init.d/MyService start`

the service (and the python app) starts fine and runs

when stopping the service manually via `sudo systemctl stop VolumioEmilClient`
strangely the python app keeps on running (checking via ps -aux and accessing the url).

Here is my Service File:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: VolumioEmilClient
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

dir="/home/pi/volumio/python_src"
cmd="python app.py"
user="pi"

name=`basename $0`
pid_file="/var/run/$name.pid"
stdout_log="/home/pi/volumio/logs/$name.log"
stderr_log="/home/pi/volumio/logs/$name.err"

get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"
}

is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps -p `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}
case "$1" in
    start)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Already started"
    else
        echo "Starting $name"
        cd "$dir"
        if [ -z "$user" ]; then
            echo "-z user"
            echo $user
            sudo $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        else
            echo "SUDO user"
            sudo -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        fi
        echo $! > "$pid_file"
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log and $stderr_log"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    ;;
    stop)
   if is_running; then
        echo -n "Stopping $name.."
        kill `get_pid`
        for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
        # for i in `seq 10`
        do
            if ! is_running; then
                break
            fi

            echo -n "."
            sleep 1
        done
        echo
        if is_running; then
            echo "Not stopped; may still be shutting down or shutdown may have failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Stopped"
            if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
                rm "$pid_file"
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running"
    fi
    ;;
       restart)
    $0 stop
    if is_running; then
        echo "Unable to stop, will not attempt to start"
        exit 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
    status)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Running"
    else
        echo "Stopped"
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

After boot I get the following output when checking the status via
`sudo systemctl status VolumioEmilClient`:

```
VolumioEmilClient.service - LSB: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/VolumioEmilClient; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-12-17 18:49:02 CET; 45s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 365 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/VolumioEmilClient start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/VolumioEmilClient.service

Dez 17 18:49:02 emil systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time...
Dez 17 18:49:02 emil VolumioEmilClient[365]: Starting VolumioEmilClient
Dez 17 18:49:02 emil VolumioEmilClient[365]: SUDO user
Dez 17 18:49:02 emil systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time.
Dez 17 18:49:02 emil sudo[374]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi/volumio/python_src ; USER=pi ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/python app.py
Dez 17 18:49:02 emil sudo[374]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Dez 17 18:49:13 emil sudo[374]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user pi
```

When, then running 
'sudo systemctl start VolumioEmilClient'
I get:

```
● VolumioEmilClient.service - LSB: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/VolumioEmilClient; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-12-17 18:52:02 CET; 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1042 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/VolumioEmilClient stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1058 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/VolumioEmilClient start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/VolumioEmilClient.service
           ├─1063 sudo -u pi python app.py
           └─1070 python app.py

Dez 17 18:52:02 emil systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time...
Dez 17 18:52:02 emil VolumioEmilClient[1058]: Starting VolumioEmilClient
Dez 17 18:52:02 emil VolumioEmilClient[1058]: SUDO user
Dez 17 18:52:02 emil sudo[1063]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi/volumio/python_src ; USER=pi ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/python app.py
Dez 17 18:52:02 emil sudo[1063]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Dez 17 18:52:02 emil systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Volumio Emil Client  at boot time.
```

Here I can see that the python app has started. Why not at boot?

Comment: Does it require resources which are not available at boot, such as a particular network service or (gasp) a GUI?

Comment: From my experience, a Python script does not detach from the startup systemd script, here `VolumioEmilClient`, by default. Therefore the Python script dies as soon as the systemd parent ends. One solution is to use a `Daemon` wrapper which detach from systemd script and start the Python script.

Comment: @tripleee no network service is required initially - only after i access the flask app running on port 8080.

Comment: @stovfl: why does the systemd parent end? Where can I find a howto on creating a Daemon wrapper?

Comment: ***"why does the systemd parent end?"***: Sorry should read *as the systemd script `VolumioEmilClient` ends*. I get i running using `openvt`, but this requires the script have to be detached using `&`. Read [implementing-a-full-python-unix-style-daemon-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217067/implementing-a-full-python-unix-style-daemon-process)